# How to use multiple Next.js middleware which each return a NextResponse object

Tags: next.js, app-router

This middleware is working correctly:

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const i18nMiddleware = createMiddleware({
        locales: ["en", "nl"],
        defaultLocale: "en",
    });

    const i18nResponse = i18nMiddleware(request);

    return i18nResponse;
}
```

This is working correctly as well:

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const { supabase, response } = createClient(request);
    await supabase.auth.getSession();
    return response;
}
```

How is it possible to consolidate these into one single middleware function, so that both i18n and auth functionality is maintained.

I've tried something like spreading the Response objects, doesn't work correctly.

Comment: All this time and nobody has answered this? I'm surprised this isn't more common, I'm running in to the same issue as well and trying to figure it out.

Comment: Stackoverflow is dead anyway